# Product of $F_{\sigma}$-screenable spaces

Tags: general-topology, paracompactness

Does anyone know if the product $X \times X$ is $F_{\sigma}$-screenable when the space $X$ is $F_{\sigma}$-screenable ?

Comment: No. See [Przymusiński](https://eudml.org/doc/211084) for counterexamples (one given is of a separable metric space $M$ and a separable, first-countable, regular Lindelöf space $Y$ for which $M\times Y$ is neither subparacompact nor metacompact).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the information and very useful reference!